# Javascript logging Objects

Tags: javascript, console

I have a strage problem with object in Javascript
Basically when I `console.log` an Object its inner objects are logging as as `"[object Object]"`

But when i log the inner object the object is logged correctly.
See the pictures below

[image]

[image]

What's wrong?

Here the content of the function: (but I don't think as a fault of the function)

```
function adjustTechs(data) {
    data.showcase.forEach(repo => {
        repo = repo.techs.map(tech => {
            return tech.name;
        })
    });
    return data.showcase
}
```

Comment: what is inside adjustTechs function?

Comment: updated @Siddharth

Comment: please provide the structure of data as well

Comment: That `.forEach()` and `.map() ` isn't doing whatever you think it is.

Comment: you right @nnnnnn

Comment: However this is the data: https://jsfiddle.net/yezxu4g6/
but the error does not reproduce itself

Comment: Solved, thanks @nnnnnn and @Siddharth. With this call
```
function adjustTechs(data) {
    data.showcase.forEach(repo => {
        repo.techs = repo.techs.map(tech => {
            return tech.name;
        })
    });
    return data.showcase
}
```